# What happens to Docker container when not shutting them down?

Tags: windows-10, docker, docker-for-windows

I am new to Docker and noticed that after starting my Docker containers and working with them, I do not shut them down but just normally restart my computer.

Now, I am wondering which effect this has on my computer? Is the Docker container's state saved when the computer is shut down and does it automatically run again after the restart?

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when restart your computer/server your container will restart with it if you have set `--restart=always` in your run command.

If you have not set it, the container will not restart and you can do it manually with `sudo docker start -it(if you need it) <name of container>`

Bye ;-)